# Xamarin Support for Android 14

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mono

Following the announcement by Microsoft that Xamarin will now support iOS 17 and Android 14 we are now looking to build our Xamarin based app to target these newer OS versions.

We are aware that Xamarin is End of Life and we are also looking at transitioning our app to .NET 7/8 but we want to target these newer OS versions to ensure we are still able to ship our existing app to the stores in the meantime.

We have been able to successfully target iOS 17 but we are having problems targeting Android 14.

When we update the Android project's .csproj file to target Android 14 we get the error: `Could not determine API level for $(TargetFrameworkVersion) of 'v14.0' (XA0000)`

We appreciate that new Android 14 APIs aren't being supported but we assumed when Microsoft announced support for Android 14 it would mean this could be selected as a target version?

Comment: Did you follow the necessary steps in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/release-notes/13/13.2?

Comment: Thanks that has clarified that we don't need to update the csproj.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've upgraded two of my X.A. projects to Android 14 by only changing the manifest using . All the Nugets are the latest versions.

Why don't you post your proj file here? Maybe there is something there that also needs changing.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation here indicates that we don't need to update the csproj we just need to update the AndroidManifest: learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/release-notes/13/13.2.

Comment: Well, why not post your problem at https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues?

Comment: We don't have a problem anymore, the documentation I linked to explains that we just need to update the manifest.